# Dropwizard Stored Procedure Example

Tags: dropwizard

I am new to dropwizard. I am going through different tutorial but I couldnt find good example/tutorial on how to call stored procedure in dropwizard using JDBI.

Answer (score 3):

With JDBI it is possible to specify an object SQL query as a method annotation. This string is treated by the DB as normal SQL. An example DAO to execute a stored procedure might look like:

```
public interface SomeQueries
{
  @SqlQuery("call find_name_procedure(:id)")
  String findName(@Bind("id") int id);
}
```

Where `find_name_procedure` has been previously defined.

For more information see http://jdbi.org/sql_object_api_queries/

Answer (score 1):

Jooq is an elegant way to call stored procedures from java (See https://dzone.com/articles/using-stored-procedures-with-jpa-jdbc-meh-just-use). You also have a thirdparty module integrating Jooq into Dropwizard
(See http://modules.dropwizard.io/thirdparty/)
So if you're familiar with Maven, you can set up the combination quickly and start validating if it works in your case.

Answer (score 1):

DropWizard JDBI provides two options to make a stored procedure call. Depending on what you want from Stored proc.

If you want resultset from Stored Proc, Andy has answered that already:

```
public interface DAO
{
  @SqlQuery("call sp_name(:id)")
  String query(@Bind("id") int id);
}
```

The other scenario is that your stored proc doesn't return resultset but gives out some output parameters. Here is what you can do:

```
@SqlCall("{ CALL sp_name(:id, :id2) }")
@OutParameter(name = "out", sqlType = Types.INTEGER)
OutParameters spCal(@Bind("id") long id, @Bind("id2") long id2);
```

OutParameter annotation may not work in DropWizard as the annotation was introduced in v3, you can use the following for accessing OutParameters:

```
try (Handle handle = dbi.open()) {
        parameters = handle.createCall("CALL sp_name(:IN_Field1,:OUT_field2)")
                .bind("IN_Field1", filed1)
                .registerOutParameter("OUT_field2", Types.INTEGER)
                .invoke();
    }
```

And for some real freaky situations where you will need both Outparameters and resultset - DropWizard currently doesn't provide any direct way (Because the JDBI version with dropwizard is old). So, you can get connection by doing below:

```
handle = jdbi.open()
handle.getConnection()
```

And then do what you want to do with the connection.

Also, one more thing - I will not try to use Hibernate for Stored Proc call. Its just more pain.

Comment: What version of dropwizard/JDBI are you using in that second example? @OutParameter looked like it appeared in JDBIv3 which isn't in Dropwizard yet or so it seems. Because In JDBI 2.73 I was utterly unable to find any "sqlobject' syntax that gives you access to the output parameters.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Annotation for OutParameter was introduced in v3. What I did was to register out paramere like shown below:

Comment: try (Handle handle = dbi.open()) {
            parameters = handle.createCall("CALL        sp_name(:IN_Field1,:OUT_field2)")
                    .bind("IN_Field1", filed1)
                    .registerOutParameter("OUT_field2", Types.INTEGER)
                    .invoke();
        }

Answer (score -1):

I used Zalando Sprocwrapper. I like it and was widely used in the Zalando company to call PostgreSQL functions.

https://github.com/zalando-incubator/java-sproc-wrapper

Comment: This repository moved and is now hosted at https://github.com/zalando-stups/java-sproc-wrapper